# show different string count for different mobile screen sizes in twig

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig, twig-filter

I have set up a rule so that if the string is over 155 then it makes this link appear for mobile only.

```html
{% if page.description|length > 155 %}
<div id="brand-desc-mobile" class="hide-on-med-and-up center-align">
<a id="modalDescBtn" class="modal-trigger" href="#modalDesc">Lire la suite</a></div>
{% endif %}
```

I was wondering if it is possible in twig to be able to show different string counts depending on the size of the screen for smaller mobile devices instead of the string count being 155 for all mobile devices?

Comment: Short answer no. Twig is rendered server side and thus can't determine anything of the client's screen size. But nothing stops you to output 2 divs with a different output which u can show/hide depending on the client's screen size

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why would the length of the string be any different on a smaller device? Or do you want to cut/trim the strings on smaller screens?

Comment: coz the link might not appear, depending on character count for smaller screen sizes? I have set in the css to cut the text to 3 lines so on smaller devices it will cut to 3 lines but it might be less than 155 so might not show the link in this case.

Comment: This is what ive used to cut the string so it only shows 3 lines. 

.sc-elle-truncate {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        max-height: 4.2em;
    }
}